TigerVNC on Debian 12
I'm trying to use TigerVNC to remote to a small thinkcenter running Debian 12 on my local network.
I ran
sudo apt install tigervnc-standalone-server tigervnc-xorg-extension tigervnc-viewer
vncpasswd
I put the following into my ~/.vnc/xstartup:
#!/bin/sh
exec cinnamon-session-cinnamon &
Then I ran vncserver

New Xtigervnc server 'debianbox:2 (xander)' on port 5902 for display :2.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /tmp/tigervnc.F1VqZJ/passwd :2 to connect to the VNC server.


=================== tail /home/xander/.vnc/debianbox:2.log ===================
==================================================================================

Session startup via '/home/xander/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!

Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session cleanly exited!
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 2639... success!

I ran the tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm suggestion but get the following when running sudo status vncserver:
○ tigervncserver@:2.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tigervncserver@.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2024-08-30 08:41:12 PDT; 46min ago
   Duration: 328ms
    Process: 808 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/tigervncsession-start :2 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 829 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 10ms

Aug 30 08:41:11 debianbox systemd[1]: Starting tigervncserver@:2.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Aug 30 08:41:11 debianbox tigervncsession[829]: pam_unix(tigervnc:session): session opened for user xander2(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
Aug 30 08:41:11 debianbox systemd[1]: Started tigervncserver@:2.service - Remote desktop service (VNC).
Aug 30 08:41:12 debianbox tigervncsession[829]: tigervncsession: tigervncserver exited with status=255
Aug 30 08:41:12 debianbox tigervncsession[829]: pam_unix(tigervnc:session): session closed for user xander2
Aug 30 08:41:12 debianbox systemd[1]: tigervncserver@:2.service: Deactivated successfully.

Any thoughts? I have the ports open ,etc. The logs of me trying to log in I think are from my Macbook's built-in VNC connection, but the connection didn't end up working.

Try it without the & in your xstartup file. I'm not sure about the details but I assume tigervnc will stop when the xstartup script ends. And when you cinnamon-session-cinnamon in background it will exit immediately. Hence the "exited too early" message.
